# Looping WORD DOC Userform Combobox Change Events & Updating Source Range in same order as UserForm controls

Tags: vba, loops, events, ms-word

Thank you ahead of time for all the help!

I am decent with VBA in Excel. But learning the differences for Word is close to learning it all from the beginning again! So please, if the solution you provide only works in WORD, please clarify so I can learn the differences.

So my goal has two major parts. I believe I solved for part 1, but can not figure out part 2. It's possible that part 1 will need to change for part 2 to work, but I tried my best over the past few weeks to figure it out and now I am finally reaching out for help.

**GOAL:**
For the purpose of a "Preview Panel" textbox within a Userform so that users can see a live result building from their control choices on the same userform. Additionally, if user changes any control choice, the live preview will update, maintaining proper order.

*Example text seen in Preview Panel after User's first pass through Userform:*

> Original Choice CB 01; Original Choice CB 02; Original Choice CB 03; etc.

*Example text seen in Preview Panel if user updates:*

> Original Choice CB 01; NEW Choice CB 02; Original Choice CB 03; etc.

**SOLVED SO FAR:** I have figured out how to pull control values into a WORD Doc Section.Last.Range, and then populate the PreviewPanel Textbox from that WORD Doc section. Here's the code I am using to do so:

```
Sub UpdateWordDoc_AfterUpdate_EVERYcontrol()

Dim docWordObj As Document
Dim cntrl As MSForms.Control
Dim SrcRng As Word.Range
Dim DestRng As Word.Range
Dim MyRng As Word.Range

Set docWordObj = Application.ActiveDocument

Set SrcRng = docWordObj.Sections.Last.Range
    SrcRng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1    

Set DestRng = docWordObj.Sections.Last.Range
    DestRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

                For Each cntrl In userform_MemoTemplate.Controls    'Me.Controls

                    If TypeName(cntrl) = "ComboBox" Then

                        With DestRng
                            .InsertAfter cntrl.Name & ": " & cntrl.Value & "; "
                            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                            .MoveEnd wdWord
                        End With

                    End If

                Next cntrl

userform_MemoTemplate.txtbx_MemoPreview.Value = SrcRng

End Sub
```

**NEED HELP:**
If a user reviews what they have entered, and decides to change combo box input, changes to the input need to be updated at the destination range IN SAME ORDER as fields appear on the userform. The only way I can imagine this, is simply reloading ALL fields via a loop.

Can I trigger such a loop when an event changes without repeating the code in all 20+ fields that will be on the Userform?

**Thank you again! Can't wait to learn how to solve this!**

**Henri**

Comment: I had to come back and read this multiple times before I sort of figured out what you're asking...  Based on what I understand you've described, my first thought is to insert each data point and *bookmark* it. You'd do that before `.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd` and probably name it using the name of the combo box? Then you can specifically target what to change in the document: `Doc.Bookmarks("Name").Range.Text = cntrl.Value` If this approach works for you, you also need code to recreate the bookmark after writing to it...